# Добавить значения оси y на линейный график

Tags: python, matplotlib, графики

Строю 7 линейных графиков в одном окне.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
data = {'Эксперт1':[5, 1, 2, 4, 3],
        'Эксперт2':[5, 1, 2, 4, 3],
        'Эксперт3':[5, 1, 2, 4, 3],
        'Эксперт4':[5, 2, 4, 3, 1],
        'Эксперт5':[5, 1, 2, 4, 3],
        'Эксперт6':[5, 1, 2, 4, 3],
        'Эксперт7':[5, 1, 2, 4, 3],
        }
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
x = [1,2,3,4,5]
plt.axis([0,7,0,6])
metki = ( 'утверждение 1', 'утверждение 2', 'утверждение 3', 'утверждение 4', 'утверждение 5')
plt.xticks(x, metki, rotation=60)
plt.plot(x,df)
plt.legend(data, loc='right')
plt.tight_layout()


plt.show()
```

Как я могу добавить на этот график к каждой линии значения по оси y, которые им соответствуют?
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: уточните, что именно вы хотите добавить: тики на оси ординат или аннотацию на самом графике?

Comment: аннотацию на самом графике. Чтобы в каждой точке перегиба писалась высота по оси y. грубо говоря, чтобы все значения из data были отражены на графиках

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
data = {'Эксперт1':[5, 1, 2, 4, 3],
#        'Эксперт2':[5, 1, 2, 4, 3],
#        'Эксперт3':[5, 1, 2, 4, 3],
        'Эксперт4':[5, 2, 4, 3, 1],
#        'Эксперт5':[5, 1, 2, 4, 3],
#        'Эксперт6':[5, 1, 2, 4, 3],
#        'Эксперт7':[5, 1, 2, 4, 3],
        }
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
x = [1,2,3,4,5]
plt.axis([0,7,0,6])
metki = ( 'утверждение 1', 'утверждение 2', 'утверждение 3', 'утверждение 4', 'утверждение 5')
plt.xticks(x, metki, rotation=60)
plt.plot(x,df)
plt.legend(data, loc='right')
plt.tight_layout()
# аннотации:
for i in df.columns:
    for j in list(zip(x, df[i])):
        plt.annotate(j[1], (j[0], j[1]))

plt.show()
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: ого как все непросто! Большое спасибо!